# Retrieve distantly related Models through "Parent" Model (Descendant Models?)

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following scenario with my models.

- User has many Companies.
- Companies have many Customers.
- Customers have many Invoices.
- Invoices have many Transactions.

What I am trying to achieve is that I can call those **$user->customers**, **$user->invoices** and **$user->transactions** on the User model. The **$user->customers** is working with a **hasManyThrough** relationship because the **customers** table has a **company_id** field which then goes to the **companies** table where a **user_id** field exists which then goes to the **users** table and checks for the **id** field. This pretty much goes like **customers->companies->user** which means it goes from each customer to the company and then to the company owner (user). This means I would want **invoices->customers->companies->user** and **transactions->invoices->customers->companies->user**.

Now the **invoices** and **transactions** tables don't have a **user_id** or **company_id** field which means I can't just put in a **hasManyThrough** as far as I know.  At the moment I am retrieving the **invoices** and **transactions** one-by-one and store them in a collection that I return.

So my problem is to figure out how to backtrack from all invoices to find the Owner (User Model) which would require to go to the customer of an invoice, from the customer to the company and than from the company to the users.

```
invoices - customer_id (Go to the Customers table)
    customers - company_id (Continue to the Companies table)
        companies - user_id (Continue to the Users table)
            users - id (This should now return all invoices)

transactions - invoice_id (Go to the Invoices table)
    invoices - customer_id (Continue to the Customers table)
        customers - company_id (Continue to the Companies table)
            companies - user_id (Continue to the Users table)
                users - id (This should now return all transactions)
```

So what I want is to get all models of a certain type that are descendant from the Company Model and return an Eloquent Collection of them to be able to paginate or further process them.

Here is a Model to give  you an idea of what I am doing at the moment.

```
<?php

namespace App;

class User extends Eloquent
{
    // Companies Table
    // - id
    // - user_id
    // ...
    public function companies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Company::class);
    }

    // Customers Table
    // - id
    // - company_id
    // ...
    public function customers()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Customer::class, Company::class);
    }

    // Invoices Table
    // - id
    // - customer_id
    // ...
    public function invoices()
    {
        $invoices = new collect([]);

        foreach ($this->customers as $customer) {
            $invoices = $invoices->merge($customer->invoices);
        }

        return $invoices;
    }

    // Transactions Table
    // - id
    // - invoice_id
    // ...
    public function transactions()
    {
        $transactions = collect([]);

        foreach ($this->invoices() as $invoice) {
            $transactions->push($invoice->transaction);
        }

        return $transactions;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those can easily be done with `belongsTo` relations.

These should allow you to be able to do `$transaction->user` or any relation in the middle

```
class Transaction extends Model
{
    public function invoice()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Invoice::class);
    }

    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->invoice->customer();
    }

    public function company()
    {
        return $this->customer->company();
    }

    public function user() 
    {
        return $this->company->user();
    }
}

class Invoice extends Model
{
    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class);
    }

    public function company()
    {
        return $this->customer->company();
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->company->user();
    }
}

class Customer extends Model
{
    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->company->user();
    }
}

class Company extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: That still wouldn't enable me to access all invoices or transactions that are related to a user through the companies and customers.

I would need something like this `$this->hasManyThrough(Invoice::class, Customer::class, Company::class);` so that Eloquent would grab the `customer_id` from the invoices table, than the `company_id` from the customers table and finally the `user_id` from the companies table to find the user everything belongs to since the invoices are not directly related to the usre.